# Elasticsearch Windows UseConcMarkSweepGC error

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I just downloaded the latest ElasticSearch 7.14.0 zip for Windows. I also downloaded the latest Logstash and Kibana. They sit on a Windows Server 2016 hosted server.

I installed the latest Java for Windows (Version 8 Update 301) from:

https://www.java.com/en/download/

On running elasticsearch.bat, I get the following error:

```
Unrecognized VM option 'UseConcMarkSweepGC'
```

I've Googled endlessly and all of the sparse forum answers are in alien technical language. I've tried commenting out the following lines in the config/jvm.options file and I still get the error.

```
# 8-13:-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
# 8-13:-XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75
# 8-13:-XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly
```

Is there a plain English answer to how I fix this? I know nothing about Java, and am just trying to learn ElasticSearch for a small project.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue but on MacOS with Elasticsearch installed via homebrew. I needed to modify the `jvm.options` and `jvm.options.default` files in `/usr/local/etc/elasticsearch/` to comment out the following lines:

**jvm.options**

```
## GC configuration
# -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
# -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75
# -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly
```

**jvm.options.default**

```
## GC configuration
# 8-13:-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
# 8-13:-XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75
# 8-13:-XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly
```

Then stopping elasticsearch (if previously running) with

```
brew services stop elasticsearch-full
```

then restarting it again with

```
brew services start elasticsearch-full
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the previous answer.
It worked for me by doing below steps:

```
Step1: Go to elasticsearch-6.5.1\elasticsearch-6.5.1\config
Step2: Open jvm.options file
Step3: Search for GC configuration
Step4: Comment below lines with #
#-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
#-XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75
#-XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly
Step5: Run elasticSearch with command: elasticsearch.bat
```